# Prevent mouse releases from happening twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery. I would like to send some JSON to the server when the user releases the mouse. Currently, the JSON is getting sent twice. How can I prevent it from happening?

Comment: releases mouse on what type of element? Where is the code? Can't troubleshoot what we can't see

Comment: On a canvas, I suppose. Thanks for being vague. I am migrating to HTML5 from Android so I am quite new here. I don't fully know HTML5 events yet.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code, it's a little challenging to understand the intent; but: you probably either are looking to do a debounce/throttle—if it's the case that a user is performing multiple clicks, and you want to ensure that a double-click would only send once within a certain timeframe—or if you really only want it to submit once and then never again, you could create a fire-once closure.

Functions that do everything you need are available in the popular [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) and [lodash](https://lodash.com/) libraries. For example, in underscore:

- [debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce)
- [throttle](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle)
- [once](http://underscorejs.org/#once)

Depending on what you're looking for, one of these functions will likely do it. The source for underscore.js is also very readable, so you can dig in and see how they're accomplishing this.